# Designated Initializer Class for a Protocol

Tags: swift

I'd like to use a protocol name as an initializer.  Something like this:

```
protocol Foo { ... }
protocol Bar : Foo { ... }

class FooImpl : Foo { ... }
```

where `let foo = Foo()` will defer to `FooImpl()` when assigning to `foo`.  Is there a way to specify a 'designated initializer class' for a protocol?

Another option might be:

```
class Foo {
  class FooImpl { ... }
  init () {
    // somehow create a FooImpl
  }
}
```

Is the above possible?  But, not sure this second case is practical given that properties can't be declared in `Foo` unless they are implemented therein.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the factory pattern here:

```
class FooFactory {
  class func createFoo -> Foo {
    return FooImpl()
  }
}

...

let foo = FooFactory.createFoo()
```